# JSON Column formatting - Joining values

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting, string

Is there a different way to join/concatenate values from 2 single line columns into a 3rd column other than the way below?

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=[$Text1] + ' and ' + [$Text2]"
}
```

I do not want to use a calculated column for this.

Columns are Text1, Text2 and Text3 is the one being formatted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yep, your alternative to an inline expression is this for concatenating values:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": {
    "operator": "+",
    "operands": [
      "[$Duration]",
      " ",
      "[$DurationUnits]"
    ]
  }
}
```

or also

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=[$Duration] + ' ' + [$DurationUnits]"
}
```

**Output (example):**

8 hour(s)

Comment: Great answer, I'd also add that you can do this online with a single line like this: `"txtContent": "=[$Duration] + ' ' + [$DurationUnits]"` Also, worth mentioning is that unlike in calculated columns, both of these fields need to be present in the view in order to access their values using list formatting.

Comment: The single line version doesn't work on my end, the other option does work